# Cannot convert value of type 'NSArray.Element' to expected argument

Tags: objective-c, swift, delegates, nsmutablearray, protocols

I have a static library writen in Objective C where I have a protocol to get the callbacks of monitoring for regions results.

```
@protocol ScanBeaconsDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void) onBeaconDetected: (NSMutableArray <Beacon*> *) detectedBeacons
@end
```

Then, when I want to use de delegate method I use like this:

```
- (void) onBeaconDetected: (NSMutableArray <Beacon*> *) detectedBeacons
{
    for(Beacon *b in detectedBeacons)
    {
        //do staff
    }
}
```

Now, I developing a project in Swift, and I want to use the protocol in the same way, but xCode traduces the delegate method like this:

```
 func onBeaconDetected(_ detectedBeacons: NSMutableArray!) {
    for beacon: Beacon in detectedBeacons
    {
        //do staff
    }
}
```

I don't know how to cast, the detectedBeacons Array to Beacon Object, im getting a "Cannot convert sequence element type 'NSArray.Element' (aka 'Any') to expected type 'Beacon'".

I am very lost, since it is my first contact with swift. is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Here Beacon is your model class??

Comment: Yes, is a customClass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
func onBeaconDetected(_ detectedBeacons: NSMutableArray!) {
  for beacon in (detectedBeacons as! [Beacon]) {
    //do staff
  }
}
```

Comment: but doing "func onBeaconDetected(_ detectedBeacons:[Beacon])", I get does not conform to protocol 'ScanBeaconsDelegate', and I cant change the static library code.